# how to upsample the superpixels to have all one shape?

Tags: python, computer-vision

Consider I have an image

[image: original]

with shape `(240, 320, 4)` and after applying the `slic` method function to `superpixels`.

I want to resize those `superpixels` in (segments 2)

[image: 2]

in order to have the same shape.

How to upsample these segments to all have super pixel size, it's ok to insert to zeros in the edges?

```
 num_segments = 400
 img = img_as_float(imread('1.png'))
 #if len(img.shape) > 2 and img.shape[-1] == 4:
     # img = img[:, :, :3]
 segments = slic(img, compactness=30, n_segments=num_segments)
 superpixels_ids = np.unique(segments)
 for id in superpixels_ids:
    pixels_per_sp = img[segments == id]
    print(pixels_per_sp.shape)

 plt.figure()
 plt.imshow(mark_boundaries(img, segments))
 plt.show()
```

the pixels_per_sp.shape have different sizes when they are plotted

```
(199, 3)
(203, 3)
(195, 3)
(232, 3)
(211, 3)
(211, 3)
(210, 3)
(210, 3)
(210, 3)
(210, 3)
(210, 3)
(210, 3)
(210, 3)
(210, 3)
(202, 3)
(210, 3)
(210, 3)
(210, 3)
(210, 3)
(210, 3)
(210, 3)
(210, 3)
(210, 3)
(180, 3)
(198, 3)
(196, 3)
```

I would like to upscale the superpixels **all** to have exactly **one size**
like if I can ad zeros in the edges of each superpixel

Another question: is there a way that I can keep the image as RGBA and apply slic still?
thnaks

Comment: It is not clear to me at all what you want to accomplish. Please [edit] your post to clarify.

Comment: I tried to explain more, please take a look

Comment: So you want to extract the pixels within each superpixel, but not preserve their relative position? If you extract each of them as a Nx3 array, you lose the neighborhood relations among these pixels. Of course you can pad this with zeros, but what effect this has depends on what you want to do with the result. What is your ultimate goal? Usually what you do is summarize each superpixel as a single node in a graph, the values of the individual pixels shouldn’t matter in most applications of superpixel segmentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, you want to have your superpixels all the same size.

*Edit 2:* I just saw that your `pixels_per_sp` are 1D arrays where it doesn't make sense to pad zeros at the end because you don't have any spatial structure in it.
I did adjust my answer below to retrieve the superpixel together with spatial neighborhood information.

So I would suggest you do the following:

- compute the minimal size of an array which still fits in all superpixels
- create such one for all of the superpixels and initialize it with zeros (your paddings)
- fill in the data of your superpixels

```py
# compute max shape
max_shape = np.zeros((len(img.shape[:-1]),), dtype=int)

for id in superpixels_ids:
    # get indices of superpixel's pixels
    pixels_indices = np.argwhere(segments == id)

    # get bounding box of superpixel
    xymin = np.min(pixels_indices , axis=0)
    xymax = np.max(pixels_indices , axis=0)

    # update max shape
    max_shape = np.max(np.stack([(xymax - xymin)+1, max_shape]), axis=0)


# create your superpixels with zero paddings

new_super_pixels = np.zeros((len(superpixels_ids), ) + tuple(max_shape) + (img.shape[-1],), dtype=img.dtype)

for i, id in enumerate(superpixels_ids):
    # get indices of superpixel's pixels
    pixels_indices = np.argwhere(segments == id)

    # get bounding box of superpixel (again)
    xymin = np.min(pixels_indices, axis=0)

    # broadcast superpixel data in our new_super_pixels array (use index instead of id)
    new_super_pixels[i][tuple((pixels_indices-xymin).T)] = img[tuple(pixels_indices.T)]
```

Now you got your array with superpixels of the same shape and padded zeros.

Does this help you?

*Edit:*

If you would like to upsample using some interpolation method, you might want to check out another [question/contribution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73662060/how-to-resize-an-arbitrary-numpy-ndarray-to-a-new-shape-with-interpolation/73662154) of mine.

Comment: Why compute minimal size of an array and not compute maximal size of an array? because when I plotted it, it showed one line as if the pixels_per_sp were down rescaled and not up scaled?

Comment: "the minimal size of an array which still fits in all superpixels" so it's practically the maximal size.

Comment: thanks for your effort, I get same size for all SP , but pixels_per_sp are 2D arrays. what should I do with new_super_pixels? because when I try to plot it, it's giving me  "raise TypeError("Invalid shape {} for image data"
TypeError: Invalid shape (380, 34, 30, 3) for image data"

Comment: new_super_pixels is an array which contains all your superpixels. If you want to plot a single superpixel, e.g., the one at index 0, you should be able to do so with plt.imshow(new_super_pixels [0])